# How to use a dictionary in my app

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Is there a way to import a dictionary or create one with Corona sdk. I have a game were the user has to create words from a base word and each time a word is submitted I need to check if it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Lua table and populate it with the words you want to store in the dictionary, using the words as keys and true as value:

```
dict = {}
dict[word] = true
```

You may want to convert words to lower case before storing or checking them:

```
word = string.lower(word)
```

The test itself is simply this:

```
if dict[word] then ...
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but that means I have to populate the whole dictionary myself. Is the any library or something that you can import to do this dictionary stuff for you?

Comment: I don't know about Corona but in Linux you can do this `for w in io.lines("/usr/share/dict/words") do dict[w]=true end`

Comment: @Gooner: There are a large number of [word list databases](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) (as text or others) that you can choose from. Really, just Google for "Word List" and you'll find plenty.